# Flask not accepting form

Tags: python, json, api, flask

I am trying to send to a flask app a simple form from python, with this requests:

```
r = requests.post('http://x.x.x.x/Files',data = {
                    'FileName': filename, 
                    'Mode' : 'Add'  
                })
```

flask app is handling it by this way:

```
api.add_resource(GetFiles, '/Files')
class GetFiles(Resource): 
    def post(self): 
        args = ParseArgs.parse_args()
        if '.txt' not in args['FileName']:
            FileName = f'{args["FileName"]}.txt'
        else: 
            FileName = args['FileName']
```

but I can't understand why, on every single request I am getting this response:

`{ "message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'." }`

I tried by setting application-json as content-type but with this result:
`{ "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" }`
in fact it wouldn't have made much sense since I'm submitting a form, but at least I tried.

I don't really understand why, I've used this app several times and it never did before, I don't know if it could be due to a new flask update since I just moved to another server and I'm using a docker container.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use `json=...` to submit a form with json data, not `data=...`.

Comment: Also, what is `ParseArgs`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use data in request the headers will be sent as form/data
If you want send as application/json you must be use json=

```
r = requests.post('http://x.x.x.x/Files', json = {
                'FileName': filename, 
                'Mode' : 'Add'  
            })
```

Comment: I don't want to send it as application/json, you can see from the app parsing that I am trying to parse a form, not a json